# WNS error 0x880403E8 on device

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, wns

I am developing a WP8.1 silverlight app, that receives WNS notification. It works fine on the emulator, but on the device (lumia 640), it crashes at the following api call:

```
var channel = await Windows.Networking.PushNotifications.PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
```

I receive the following error:

> - _exception  {System.Exception: Exception from HRESULT: 0x880403E8
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>     at BC_Menu.App.<UploadChannel>d__0.MoveNext()
>     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>     at BC_Menu.StartUp.FirstPage.d__4.MoveNext()
>     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.b__3(Object state)}    System.Exception

If I try on another device (lumia 920), it works fine. The immediate difference between the devices are that I have a dummy account on the Lumia 640 and no sim card, but I am able to install and update programs. Which should mean the account is correctly initialized. What else could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're crashing because the Windows.Networking.PushNotifications.PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync() call is throwing an exception because the device is not connected to WNS. Make sure you handle that case (e.g. with a try/catch) - your users may not always be connected to the internet, which is required to get a channel.

As for why that device isn't connecting to WNS - if you have *no* SIM card, the device should connect via Wi-Fi. If you're developing in an enterprise make sure they're not blocking outbound connections (which would cause the device to be unable to connect to WNS). If you have a SIM card installed but it has no data, there is a known bug where the device will still try to connect via cellular data (which of course fails). If that's the case, just remove the data-less SIM or disable cellular.