# unable to get channel uri for UWP Windows notification service

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.uwp, wns

I am trying to write a code to receive windows push notification in xamarin.

so far i am able to get the `package SID`, `application id` and `client secret` key from the windows developer account. later on i have associate my app from visual studio 2017.

when i am trying to use following code to get channel uri i am getting errors

`var channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();`

**Error without application id**

[image]

**Error with application id**

[image]

1. i am running my build on Local Machine having windows 10
2. i have tried to connect my machine using local network , wifi and even with mobile hotspot just to check whether anything is blocking to make connection with WNS server.
3. i am using `Windows 10 sdk Anniversary Edition 1493`

Comment: This code works well in my side, where do you call this method in your code? Moreover, could you try to restart your device and test it again?

Comment: i have written this code in `MainPage.xaml.cs` which is in `Universal Windows` xamarin build. I am not running on device , i am running this code on `Local Machine`

Comment: @Hunt Is this still unresolved for you?

Comment: Yes it's still unresolved

Comment: @Hunt Is this still unresolved?